# настройка Apache2:

Tags: apache2

установил Apache2, UBUNTU не показивает директорию /home/user/public_html/ показ скритих файлов включен. на https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP написано, что директория должна бить.

Answer (score 2):

Я надеюсь вы подставляете вместо "user" имя настоящего пользователя? И по приведённой вами ссылке не написано, что директория должна бить. Там написано "As an example" и "If you have not created /home/user/public_html/, you will receive an warning message". Так что создайте каталог вручную (командой mkdir) или укажите в конфигурации Apache какой-либо другой. И, разумеется, используйте вместо "user" имя вашего пользователя.

Comment: спасибо, установил Denver на windows10 все работает.